# How to set path of any image in background in css in Hostinger at the time of hosting website?

Tags: html, css

I developed a webpage and set some background images in css like:

**html**

```
<div class="expertise1-img1"></div>
```

**css**

```
.expertise-img1{
     background-image: url('../img/expertise/Angularjs.png');
     background-repeat: no-repeat;
     background-position: center;
     background-size: 18vh;
}
```

, and all images were shown properly in localhost.
But when i hosted that web page in hostinger, none of the images are shown.Please tell me the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Check whether all the folders and images are moved properly to your host, and also check your URL which mapped correctly or not.